# What "Replacement Pattern" should I choose for Content Type / Node Type in Colorbox popup?

Tags: nodes, tokens, javascript

I am using the [Colorbox](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module and I need the type of the content to be displayed in the popup. 
These are the default Replacement Pattern,

```
[title] == Content: Title
[field_event_date] == Content: Date
[body] == Content: Body
```

Can anyone tell me what should I choose for Content Type Name?

I have tried [type], [content-type], [node-type], [node:type]. But nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like some of the things you've tried would be correct. Are you saying those tokens are not available at all?

Comment: I have tried these tokens [type], [content-type], [node-type], [node:type], but they didn't work. It might be because I am using them in Colorbox. Because they work in "Rules".

Comment: Sounds like it's potentially a problem with Colorbox then, and you should go to it's issue queue. I can't immediately see a reason why they'd accept different sets of token.s